# PCA loadings plot organization?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I was wondering if there is a way to organize this loadings plot so that the "o1, o2,..." can be clean and also whether colour can be added let's say to individual arrows that show the greatest contribution while the others faded.

Here is what I have for now:

```
ggplot(loadings1)+geom_segment(aes(xend=PC1,
yend=PC2),x=0,y=0,arrow = arrowstyle)+
geom_text(aes(x=PC1,y=PC2,label=row.names(loadings1)),
hjust=1,vjust=2,size=3,
color='red')+xlim(-0.2,0.3)+ylim(-0.3,0.3)
```

[image: Loadings plot I did using the code in the post :)]

Comment: What do you mean by "clean"? And can you provide some code to produce `loadings1`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `FactoMineR` library.

A small example below.

```
library("FactoMineR")
res.pca <- PCA(df,  graph = FALSE)
get_eig(res.pca)
```

output

```
##        eigenvalue variance.percent cumulative.variance.percent
## Dim.1   4.1242133        41.242133                    41.24213
## Dim.2   1.8385309        18.385309                    59.62744
## Dim.3   1.2391403        12.391403                    72.01885
## Dim.4   0.8194402         8.194402                    80.21325
## Dim.5   0.7015528         7.015528                    87.22878
## Dim.6   0.4228828         4.228828                    91.45760
## Dim.7   0.3025817         3.025817                    94.48342
## Dim.8   0.2744700         2.744700                    97.22812
## Dim.9   0.1552169         1.552169                    98.78029
## Dim.10  0.1219710         1.219710                   100.00000
```

Plot

`fviz_pca_var` This function helps you to graph of variables.

```
fviz_pca_var(res.pca, col.var="contrib",
             gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
             repel = TRUE)
```

`col.var`: color for individuals and variables, respectively. Can be a continuous variable or a factor variable. Possible values include also : "cos2", "contrib", "coord", "x" or "y". In this case, the colors for individuals/variables are automatically controlled by their qualities of representation ("cos2"), contributions ("contrib"), coordinates (x^2+y^2, "coord"), x values ("x") or y values ("y"). To use automatic coloring (by cos2, contrib, ....), make sure that habillage ="none".

`gradient.cols`: vector of colors to use for n-colour gradient. Allowed values include brewer and ggsci color palettes.

`repel`: a boolean, whether to use ggrepel to avoid overplotting text labels or not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I decided that because I wanted to specifically pick the variables that produce the variance observed in the PCA w/ ellipse I formed this:

```
arrowstyle<-arrow(length = unit(0.07,"inches"),type = "closed")
og1<-ggplot(loadings1)+geom_segment(aes(xend=PC1,
          yend=PC2),x=0,y=0,arrow = arrowstyle,
          color=loadings1$class)+
  geom_text(aes(x=PC1,y=PC2,label=row.names(loadings1)),
            hjust=1,vjust=2,size=3,
            color='black')+xlim(-0.2,0.3)+ylim(-0.3,0.3)+
  theme_light()+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black",
                                   size = 10),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black",
                                   size = 10),
        axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "black",
                                    size = 10),
        axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "black",
                                    size = 10),
        axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black",
                                    fill = NA,size = 1))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,linetype="dashed",color="gray69")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0,linetype="dashed",color="gray69")
```

And I do like! The issue now is that I can seem to control the length of the line, not the arrow, but the line. I want to decrease it slightly and I am trying to figure out how!
Any ideas??

[Here is what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLF7o.jpg)